# OpenCV 3.1. SURF and SIFT C++

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, sift, surf

Does anyone have solution for this problem:

```
Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create(minHessian);

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object;

detector->detect( inImage, keypoints_object );
```

It gives me Unhandeled exeption error while going throu detect function. I have linked the xfeatures2d module and included it into file, also I included nonfree.hpp, which is part of xfeatures2d. In earlier versions, this problem was solved using `initModule_nonfree()`, I think, but here, this function do not exist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: initModule was a function from pure C, that should not be necessary. Check if the parameter for the create function is fine, or if the input image is valid...

Comment: take a look at offical sample [surf_matcher.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/samples/surf_matcher.cpp)

Comment: did you try adding  using namespace cv::xfeatures2d

Comment: thank you for your answers. I have already tried all of that. I have implemented my surf detector, before I realised that I have built xfeatures2d as 32bit, and the rest of my modules is x64. That was the error.